# Delete remote branch accidentally

Tags: git, github

I have a remote branch which i checkout out just now. I want to delete some other branch but accidentally deleted "Development" branch.

```
git push origin :Development
```

Now i tried to get it back by this command

```
git push origin head
```

is this the same as

```
(git push origin Development :Development)
```

Will this have any impact ? Any other thing that i need to do in order to remain this brach same as previous.

One Impact I have seen:-

```
All pull requests were declined which were not approved before deletion.
```

Do we have to send pull request again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this have any impact ?

If your local development branch was up-to-date, there won't be any impact.
The remote repo will recover that branch with its history intact.

The only way the new remote branch would defer from the one deleted is that you changed its history locally (like with a rebase)

Comment: I just checked out branch by **git pull --rebase** and then deleted it by **git push origin :Development** and then tried to get it back by **git push origin head**. Will it be fine with all things intact. Because pull requests were declined in this process. Do I have to send pull request again.

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta if the pull --rebase was done while you were locally on Development, the next push will work in restoring that branch. As for a PR branch, you can push it or force push it multiple time without having to send a PR again.

Comment: Okay thanks. So this would not have any impact. Sending the pull requests again will also do the work.